# What is a thing with a stone and has a finger?

Tags: riddle

I have stone on my head;
and a finger in my mouth;
Who am I?

This is a riddle I am trying to find out what is this thing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are

> A ring. The stone on your head is a gem set in the top of the ring, your mouth is the 'ring shape' through which a finger goes

Comment: oh yes indeed. Thanx :)

Answer (score 4):

> A ring. A ring has a stone (a gemstone) on its head (top part) and a finger in its mouth (opening).

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Great answer, but next time, please use spoiler tags so that other people can solve the puzzle without seeing your answer. You can do this by putting a >! before the text you want to hide.

Comment: I beg your pardon. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's

> Ring......
>  A ring has a stone on it and has a finger inside it.